# ORA-01196: file 1 is inconsistent due to a failed media recovery session

Tags: oracle, restore, recovery, rman

I have 3 database 1 primary and two standby, The storage of one the standby was abruptly removed without shutting down the database.

Few Days later the storage was returned, I restart the whole database server, and while trying to open my database instance(alter database open) I get the errors below:

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-10458: standby database requires recovery
ORA-01196: file 1 is inconsistent due to a failed media recovery session
ORA-01110: data file 1: '+DATA/drstby/datafile/system.306.918916853'

I tried to do "recover database;" and I get another error:

RMAN-03002: failure of recover command at 12/15/2017 17:11:50
RMAN-06054: media recovery requesting unknown archived log for thread 1 with sequence 62585 and starting SCN of 16625729961

Please what can I do.

Note:
the database in question has the following
FRA
ASM
RMAN BACKUPS.
THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to restore archivelogs. If you have them backed up to tape, you may need to do something like:

```
run
{
  allocate channel ch1 type 'sbt_tape' parms
  restore archivelog from scn 16625729961 until scn 999999999;
}
```

Replace the until scn 999999999 with an appropriate scn from your primary database.